# Citations across tex files

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I have a strange problem that I can't resolve.

In my main *.tex file I have

```
\input{Chapter1VB.tex}
\input{vbq.tex}
\newpage
\input{Chapter2VB.tex}
```

In the first tex file I have

```
\begin{thm}\label{thm1.3}
```

In the third I have

```
(which exists by Theorem~\cite{thm1.3}
```

No matter how many times I 'latex' or 'pdflatex' I keep getting a warning that thm1.3 is undefined.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\cite` macro should be used to cite bibliography references (marked by `\bibitem` inside a `thebibliography` environment). For cross-references (marked by `\label`), use `\ref` instead of `\cite`.

Note: You may use packages like [cleveref](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) to automatically add "Theorem" (or whatever term is appropriate) to a cross-reference.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{first.tex}
\begin{thm}\label{thm1.3}
Some text.
\end{thm}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{second.tex}
\dots~which exists by Theorem~\ref{thm1.3}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\input{first}

\input{second}

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: opps, I did know that. I'll blame...Friday-itis